# Reading Value From Google Distance Matrix API C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I Have the Following XML Packet which comes from Google.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <DistanceMatrixResponse>
  <status>OK</status> 
  <origin_address>Poplar Drive, Kingsbridge, Devon TQ7 1SF, UK</origin_address> 
  <destination_address>1 Saint Michaels Road, Kingsteignton, Newton Abbot, Devon TQ12 3AQ, UK</destination_address> 
- <row>
- <element>
  <status>OK</status> 
- <duration>
  <value>2710</value> 
  <text>45 mins</text> 
  </duration>
- <distance>
  <value>37958</value> 
  <text>38.0 km</text> 
  </distance>
  </element>
  </row>
  </DistanceMatrixResponse>
```

Now what I am trying to do is assign the two values fields to variables.

I have pulled this into a Stream IE.

```
Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://ho-www/GoogleApiAccess/DistanceMatrix.aspx?origins=" + orilat + "," + orilong + "&destinations=" + destlat + "," + destlong + "&mode=driving'&units=imperial'&language=en'&sensor=false' (http://ho-www/GoogleApiAccess/DistanceMatrix.aspx?origins=" + orilat + "," + orilong + "&destinations=" + destlat + "," + destlong + "&mode=driving%27&units=imperial%27&language=en%27&sensor=false%27)");
```

Everything I have searched for so far only tells me how to get to the parent elements ie duration and distance but not how to get underneath.

This should be a simple answer but I just cant think it through...

Can any help put me out my misery!

Comment: Post some codes showing how you get the parent elements. I'm sure it isn't hard to modify what you have to be able to get the child elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of doing what you asked, and I don't know which way you're more familiar with. That's why I asked you to post codes you have at the moment.

The other answer already demonstrates one way using `XmlDocument` and XPath selector syntax. This is another possible way using LINQ-to-XML's `XDocument` and the method chain syntax :

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
var duration = (string)doc.Root
                          .Element("row")
                          .Element("element")
                          .Element("duration")
                          .Element("value");
var distance = (string)doc.Root
                          .Element("row")
                          .Element("element")
                          .Element("distance")
                          .Element("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using XPath

```
var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.Load(stream);

var durationValueNode = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//duration/value");
var durationValue =  durationValueNode ==null ? "" : durationValueNode.InnerText;

var distanceValueNode = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//distance/value");
var distanceValue = distanceValueNode == null ? "" : distanceValueNode.InnerText;
```